# Special link on gmail inbox linking

Tags: gmail, email

I don't really know the name given to this but if you receive mail from trello, you will see a link 'open card in trello'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cFoX.png)

How can achieve this with a programming language? preferably php

Comment: So what is your question or issue with this?